# Safely replace table with new data and schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a stored procedure to recreate a table from scratch, with a possible change of schema (including possible additions/removals of columns), by using a `DROP TABLE` followed by a `SELECT INTO`, like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DROP TABLE [MyTable]
SELECT (...) INTO [MyTable] FROM (...)
COMMIT
```

My concern is that errors could be generated if someone tries to access the table after it has been dropped but before the `SELECT INTO` has completed. Is there a way to lock `[MyTable]` in a way that will persist through the DROP?
Instead of `DROP/SELECT INTO`, I could `TRUNCATE/INSERT INTO`, but this would not allow the schema to be changed. `SELECT INTO` is convenient in my situation because it allows the new schema to be automatically determined. Is there a way to make this work safely?

Also, I would like to be sure that the source tables in "FROM (...)" are *not* locked during this process.

Comment: I would be hesitant about doing this in an sproc.  The [doc for DROP TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql) says, "DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur."  An sproc, AFAIK, is all one batch.  It wouldn't surprise me if SELECT INTO had the same trouble.  If you truly need to dynamically modify schema like this, you might need to look into an Entity-Attribute-Value table.  They're gross and hard to query, but they allow you to have a fixed schema.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know! The source data here is actually a Entity-Attribute-Value table and the purpose of this procedure is to maintain a version of the data which is easier to query and higher performing. The schema will change relatively rarely, so if necessary that could be handled by a different process, and I could just do TRUNCATE/INSERT in the stored procedure. In that case, what is the proper way to lock the table? Just put WITH (TABLOCKX) on the TRUNCATE statement?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that WITH (TABLOCKX) is not allowed on a TRUNCATE. I've seen "SELECT 1 FROM [MyTable] WITH(TABLOCKX)" to lock a table, but it just seems odd that it would be necessary to query the table in order to lock it; is there a cleaner way?

Comment: For that you can use something like `SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM MyTable WITH (TABLOCK,HOLDLOCK)` or you can use the `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to make a significant change to the table (like adding a column in the middle of existing columns, not at the end) using SSMS and see what script it generates, you'll see that SSMS uses [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql).

The general structure of the SSMS's script:

- create a new table with temporary name
- populate the new table with data
- drop the old table
- rename the new table to the correct name.

All this in a transaction.

This should keep the time when tables are locked to a minimum.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT (...) INTO dbo.Temp_MyTable FROM (...)

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable

EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Temp_MyTable', N'dbo.MyTable', 'OBJECT'

COMMIT
```

`DROP TABLE MyTable` acquires a schema modification (Sch-M) lock on it until the end of transaction, so all other queries using `MyTable` would wait. Even if other queries use the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level (or the infamous `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint).

See also MSDN [Lock Modes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx):

> ## Schema Locks
>
> The Database Engine uses schema modification (Sch-M)
>   locks during a table data definition language (DDL) operation, such as
>   adding a column or dropping a table. During the time that it is held,
>   the Sch-M lock prevents concurrent access to the table. This means the
>   Sch-M lock blocks all outside operations until the lock is released.